# how to update latest value to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I have a ng-click function that work as "up vote button" it increases the number of vote by 1 and each user only can vote once, the way I use to detect "one user only can vote once" is to compare their user_id to voted_id if their user_id is in the voted_id then they will not be able to vote, but the problem is i can't set the updated voted_id list that fetched from database to a variable.In other word, the user can vote multiple time, unless the user refresh the page and the latest voted_id is update to the variable.

I'm not sure the way i do it is correct or not if you guys have better suggestion please tell me, your suggestion is much appreciated.
this is what i have so far

```
$scope.up = function(){
          if(s_session != null){ // check if user logged in or not 
            data.getUserData().success(function(userData){ // get user data
              $scope.a = {};
              $scope.b = {};
              $scope.a = data1.votes.voted_id; // set voted_id(it is an array)
              $scope.b = userData._id; // set user_id
            if($scope.a.indexOf($scope.b) == -1){ // if it is not in the list
                                                  // perform upvote action 
          $scope.user ={};
          $scope.user = userData;
          $scope.user.permalink = $routeParams.permalink;
          $http.post('/contentHandler/Post/vote/up',$scope.user).
          success(function(updatedData) {
          $scope.a = updatedData.votes.voted_id; // after upvoted
                                                // re-set the latest voted_id to
                                               // $scope.a and prevent the user
                                              // to vote again
            }).error(function(err){

            });
            }else{
              alert("you can't vote twice");
            }
            });
            }else{
              $location.path('/login');
            }
          }
```

Comment: I made an upvote system in PHP-MySQL and to prevent duplicated votes, I just made a table where the votes are stored (who made them and in which page), and then, when the user votes, the system checks that table to find if the pair user-page already exists. And it works.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what data you're trying to compare and where it comes from.  What is compared in this line? `if($scope.a.indexOf($scope.b) == -1)` Are they objects?  Or simple values?

Comment: @Reboog711 sorry for my poor elaboration, the line you're referring to  is actually to compare the "user_id" with "voted_id" by using indexOf because i store the "voted_id" in array(it is an array that contain user who voted). if the result is -1 which mean it is not in the list then it will perform the "upvote action" else it means the user user_id is in the voted_id which mean he/she already voted so they can't vote again

Comment: Are  both user_id and voted_id integers?  Have you tested the results of the compare? I think I'd need a runnable sample to look deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you actually increasing the number of votes? You could set up a temporary `userHasNotVoted` boolean variable on the client side (basically in angular scope) to prevent them from casting multiple votes before a page reload.

Add the variable to the scope as shown below:

```
$scope.userHasNotVoted = true;

$scope.up = function(){
    if(userHasNotVoted){
        $scope.userHasNotVoted = false;
        //add vote and record it in the db
        // do whatever else
    }
}
```